# Styled-system in react native responsive values

Tags: react-native, styled-components, styled-system

I am trying to use styled-system library in my react native app . I want to use responsive style in my box component but I get error "Node of type atrule not supported as an inline style". How can I fix this warning ?

//theme

```
 export const space = {
    NONE: 0,
    S: 4,
    M: 8,
    L: 16,
    XL: 32,
   
  };
```

// component

```
 <Box flex={0.5} bg="text" marginTop={["S","M","L","XL"]}/>
```

Comment: this is what I saw in StyledSystem documentation :    // responsive margin
<Box m={[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]} />, then maybe the problem is with your string type, and it should be number instead of string: {[space .S, space.M, space.L, space.XL]}

Comment: It didn't work. It's the same with  space=[0,4,8,12]  <Box m ={[1,2,3,4}]/>